# How to change TextBox's background when it got focus?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I can change `TextBox`'s Foreground, Background, etc. but when the textbox got focus, it's background gets white. How can I set it to be transparent (Or any other color)?

```
<TextBox Foreground="Black" SelectionBackground="Black" SelectionForeground="White" Background="Transparent" Text="Hello!"/>
```

(it's a windows phone program, but not be so different than WPF)

Comment: have you tried the `Textbox.GotFocus` event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm, maybe I don't get it, but I think it's doable, and easy, just on you GotFocus event, add this line:

```
textbox1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Cyan); //Cyan for example.
```

That works for you?

Comment: He means when you click on the textbox. If you do your solution it will turn white when focused

Comment: @AMR Actually the backgroud will have an standard color, but will only change once the control gets the focus. And you can change it back once it lost the focus.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set the focused background on the Windows Phone Textbox.

I ran into this exact problem in my most recent app. ([Cornet - For Web Developers](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/cornet/5f5dbf81-5084-4fcc-ac60-bf3a3880f9e0))

I handled it by putting a rectangle behind it and filled it with the colors I needed. This is a ghetto solution. The better option would be to create a custom control.

You can see how it looks in my app

Comment: I tried to set a rectangle behind the textbox, but it's always white regardless what color is behind it. how did you do that? thanks.